# Why was this duplicate flag declined when the target dupe clearly answered the question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380102/how-can-i-send-a-specific-message-to-a-channel-error-below) has the same error in the question I marked it as a duplicate for ([How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)). They both contain the same error, the same problem, and the same answer. Can anyone tell me why the 3 reviewers chose **Leave Open**?

Comment: Another interesting question: why did you post an answer to that question, if you thought it was a duplicate?

Comment: I answered it before I realized it was extremely similar

Comment: @yivi You can't get rep from closing as dupe and you prevent competing answers when closing a question. So a win-win for some users.

Comment: Not a subject matter expert, but I don't see how those are duplicates... The linked question has a code and a very specific error. The suggested duplicate has a bunch of random errors and none of them include the one in the question (`message.guild.channels.get`)...

Comment: They both have answers about Managers and the `cache` property. I've seen other questions closed as duplicates for that before

Comment: @yivi should I delete the answer since the other one is better?

Comment: I wouldn't post an answer or leave an answer up if I was convinced a question was a duplicate. I don't know if this one is actually a dupe or not. If it's a dupe, I'm sure the OP would appreciate a comment explaining them how the dupe applies, or maybe edit the dupe answer so it covers this scenario more fully. (I don't know anything about Discord.js, though).

Comment: Regarding your actual question here on meta, only the reviewers can tell you why they clicked which button. We can try to guess, but that's all we can do. Most likely they disagreed, wrongly or rightly.

Comment: Alright I edited the dupe, and removed my answer. Would flagging again be worth it?

Comment: @MrMythical I have to agree with Tomerikoo. While it may be obvious after reading the duplicate link that it's a duplicate, the source question **lacks enough written context** that the OP is using v12 (or above).

Comment: It's actually pretty obvious because that error only occurs either with an object they made themselves (which I assume they didn't), or if they are on v12 or above

Comment: It may be not so obvious for the reviewers who don't necessarily have knowledge of discord.js.

Comment: That makes sense, but if they didn't really have knowledge of discord.js, wouldn't it be hard to determine if it was a duplicate?

Comment: *"you prevent competing answers when closing a question"* not when you close as a dupe, @Tom . People are still free to post answers on the dupe candidate. Also, rep farming is *not* a reason to not close a question that should be closed.

Comment: @Larnu Every answer competes with every answer posted somewhere else, but that doesn't matter then a reader reads that post. Some might follow the dupe link, but not all and they vote on the existing answers on the post they are right now. Also, you might have missed the obvious context of my comment, the question why OP posted an answer instead of just closing. So your comment regarding rep farming isn't a reason for not closing is a swing and a miss.

Comment: I've not missed it at all, @Tom , the OP can get rep by posting on the dupe target.

Comment: What I would really say is that it has the same *concept*.

Comment: I'd rather your answer on the new question stay specifically for users who encounter that one error rather than sending users to a conglomerate of assorted errors and fixes to dig through to find their specific case. *also* linking it as a duplicate wouldn't detract from the Q&A's usefulness.

Comment: that said, i still don't see where that specific problem in question A is mentioned in question B. Both may be migration issues (the user is likely copying code from an older blog or tutorial,) but that isn't enough to make it a duplicate. Should it be edited into the larger "migration breaking changes" post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> They both contain the same error

No, they don't.  There's nothing on the proposed target about `message.guild.channels.get`, and as someone not familiar with the library, it's not immediately obvious that this is one of the things that was changed to a manager (a fact that I was able to deduce only by looking at your deleted answer and then searching for "cache" on the target).

> the same problem

Kiiind of.  One asks how to send a message to a specific channel, an answer to which would be useful in its own right, even for people not migrating.  The other asks how to migrate code.  The root cause of the crash is similar, though.

> and the same answer

Again, kind of.  A good answer to this question would address the titular question "How can I send a specific message to a channel?" in addition to addressing why they're getting that specific error.  This would make the question more useful to future people trying to do *that*.